# Having trouble with LinqPad Adding a Connection to Entity Framework

Tags: linqpad

I am new to Entity Framework and Linq to Entities and I want to try LinqPad but I can't figure out how to make a connection to the edmx model I have created.
I have an MVC project and I added an ADO.Net Entity Data Model against a SQL Sever database ( a Development server, not one on my local machine) Did a Build.Right click in my designer surface and Add Code Generation Item. That has given me two .tt folders, one for my dbContext class, one with all my classes.

Open LinqPad click on Add Connection. Point to the .dll file in my solutions bin folder, then in the Full Type Name of dbContext I choose the entity I created. Now is whee I am having trouble making this work. I point to the solution web.config file and when I click the Test button I get an error saying "Could not load file or assembly 'Entity Framework version=..." &  "The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\users..\web.config line 9" Any ideas?

Comment: It says that it cannot fine the web.config file... does that file exist? You can specify the location of the config file in LINQPad's dialog.

Comment: Hi, yes it does. I have tried again and after browsing to the web.config file I get a connection but I get a red x and the error "The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I took **configSections** away from config file and connection works.

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will re install LinqPad and try removing the configSections to see if that works for me.

Comment: OK, I remarked out the configSections and it now works. As a side note, I only seemed to need to remark the configSections for projects using SQL Server 2008 as a datasource, I had no troubles with projects using SqlExperss on my local machine. Not sure now what the configSections  is used for since my project works just fine with it being remarked out. Now, off to start playing with LinqPad.

Answer (score 4):

I've had this exact problem with LinqPad 4.42.01.  My project is a web project using an EF5 data assembly.  I ended up creating a linqPad.config file (below) in the web projectMy and it works great.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <remove name="MySqlServer"/>
      <add name="MySqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=mydb;Initial Catalog=mycat;User ID=iamuser;Password=soopersekret;Trusted_Connection=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```